# How to fill getItemSize() method in my java code

Tags: java

I have a DListNode class with a member name item.

```
/* DListNode.java */

/**
 * DListNode is a node in DList(Doubly linked list). 
 * @author mohet01
 *
 */
public class DListNode {

    /**
     * item references the item stored in the current node.
     * prev references the previous node in the DList.
     * next references the next node in the DList.
     */

    Object item;
    DListNode prev;
    DListNode next;

    /**
     * DListNode constructor with zero args
     */
    public DListNode(){
        this.item=null;
        this.prev=null;
        this.next=null;
    }

    /**
     * DListNode constructor with one arg
     */
    public DListNode(Object obj){
        this.item = obj;
        this.prev = null;
        this.next = null;
    }


    /**
     * getItem() returns the size of the queried item
     * @return
     */

    public Object getItemSize() {
         //solution required    
         return item;
    }
}
```

If DListNode member item points to object of type TypeAndSize class,

```
public class TypeAndSize {

    public int type;            //Ocean.EMPTY, Ocean.UNVISITEDSHARK, or Ocean.FISH
    public int size;                        // Number of cells in the run



    /**
     * Constructor for a TypeAndSize of specified species and run length.
     * @param species is Ocean.EMPTY, Ocean.SHARK, or Ocean.FISH.
     * @param runLength is the number of identical cells in this run.
     * @return the newly constructed Critter.
     * 
     */

    public TypeAndSize(int species, int runLength){

        if((species != Ocean.EMPTY) && (species != Ocean.SHARK) && (species != Ocean.FISH)){
            System.out.println("TypeAndSize Error: Illegal species.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if(runLength < 1){
            System.out.println("TypeAndSize Error: runLength must be atleast 1.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        this.type = species;
        this.size = runLength;
    }


    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

}
```

My goal is to bring the member size by writing code in  getItemSize() method of DListNode class.
These above two classes are skeletons given by professor.
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/pj1/

I created getSize() method in TypeAndSize class.

Please help me!!!

FYI...
This is my first experience in using such scenario, as am learning java at home from cs61B Fall 2006 Berkeley course webcast. This is part of assignment in Project1

Please help me!!!

Comment: What i know is, i was able to implement equals() method in DListNode class by actually performing equals() on TypeAndSize class by using polymorphism in java. Below method in TypeAndSize class, which gets called when member item.equals(other.item); is invoked from DListNode class             @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj)
   return true;
  if (obj == null)
   return false;
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
   return false;
  TypeAndSize other = (TypeAndSize) obj;
  if (type != other.type)
   return false;
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will call this method only on the first of the elements of the list, this should solve your problem:

```
public int getItemSize() {
    int size = 0;
    DListNode node = this;
    while (node != null) {
        size++;
        node = node.next;
    }
    return size;
}
```

If you want this to be called from any node, use this other solution

```
 public Object getItemSize() {
    int size = 0;
    DListNode node = this;
    while (node != null) {
        size++;
        node = node.next;
    }
    node = prev;
    while (node != null) {
        size++;
        node = node.prev;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: sorry joao, you misunderstood my question,  DListNode class has member 'Object item'. and this item is pointing to object of type TypeAndSize in runtime. TypeAndSize class has member 'int size'. I need this 'size' by calling getSize() method of TypeAndSize class from getItemSize() method of DListNode class. Hope this will clarify my question.

Comment: Hey can i do this?  /**
  * getItemSize() returns the size of the queried item
  * @return
  */

 public int getItemSize() {
  return ((TypeAndSize)item).getSize();
 }

Comment: If some ACK my solution in my previous update, downcasting that i did, would have been avoided in my previous update, if Object class had getSize() method. so are these the scenarios where down casting is used? please respond, am stuck up here, I would like to understand, if am doing proper programming here.